# DIsplaying preview image from input file

Tags: jquery

The problem lies in the "this", if i change that to "#photo1", the image will be able to display.

I have a few file input and that's why I need to edit my code. I have no idea what is happening.

```
$(".pro-set-up-photo-preview").hide();

    $("#photo1").change(function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
            $(this).next().next("img").attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        // read the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        $(this).next().next("img").show();
    });
```

Here is my [**CODE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dr3am3rz/o9onxrc7/3/)

Comment: check this url http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: Hi Sharma, thanks for the help. I have already saw this solution before but I have a few inputs and my code will be too long if I add it 1 by 1. That is why I have edited to the code I am using.

Comment: $(".pro-set-up-photo-preview").hide();
 
$("#photo1").change(function () {
  var reader = new FileReader();

 reader.onload = function (e) {
  // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
  $('.pro-set-up-photo-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
 };
 
 // read the image file as a data URL.
 reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
 $(this).next().next("img").show();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in the nested function is referencing the `FileReader` object. You should save the reference to #photo1 in a local variable before the `reader.onload` callback:

```
var photo = $(this);
```

and then use `photo` instead of `$(this)`:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
    photo.next().next("img").attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! Thanks a lot! I should have posted this question earlier, wasted so much time trying to solve this issue. My JS isn't that good. Thanks Sebastian! =D